# Is It Bad Practice to Run 3 Copy MD Raid10 Array in Degraded State?

Tags: raid, software-raid, mdadm, raid10

**Is it bad practice to run a 3 copy MD RAID10 array on two drives with a missing drive in place of a 2 copy MD RAID10 array on two drives to allow for the addition of a third drive in the future?**

We are migrating servers and I will build a new array on the new server. The plan is to build a 3 copy array with a missing drive and leave it this way possibly for months to allow for the addition of a third drive in the future.  **Is this equivalent to running a 2 copy array or are there caveats to this?**

Our current array is a 2 copy MD RAID10 array on two drives. We would like to add another level of redundancy but *we do not have the third drive yet or the tray for it* and nothing is pressing us make the purchase to implement this immediately.

Comment: A RAID10 is not possible with 2 HDDs, you need at least 4 HDDs for a RAID10. In general it's possible to start an array in degraded state, but I wouldn't recommend this. RAID10 means that you have a RAID0 built from several RAID1 arrays. If you start with one degraded RAID1 and that disk fails, all your RAID10 data is trashed.

Comment: @Thomas MD RAID10 differs from true nested RAID1+0; a 2 drive MD RAID10 is possible.  See https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles10/stor_admin/data/raidmdadmr10cpx.html or any other MDADM documentation you can find.  In our case, a 2 drive MD RAID 1 had almost half the performance of our current 2 drive MD RAID 10 so we run it as is.  Further, you can create any number of copies you want up to the number of devices; hence the question about a 3 copy 3 drive MD RAID10 created with a missing device.

Comment: thanks for updating. Didn't know that the layout of RAID10 is so different with `mdadm`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the biggest loss would be that you lose the ability to easily tell if the array is broken (due to a failed drive) or not.